# What do the lines behind icons mean? How to remove?

Tags: home-screen, app-icons, icon-packs

On a LG G5, I see that the icons of apps are often shown with some added lined symbols behind  it, which are not part of the icons design itself.

There are squares, triangles, variants of mirrored or rotated Z, H, and others:

[image]

I'd be curious of it's meaning.

Is that just on my device, and i must have made an unintended theme change somehow?

**If not - how to get rid of the lines!**

Comment: Can you upload an example image?

Comment: Yes, I do use the Apex launcher. This launcher shows the icons without lines.

Comment: @beeshyams After switching to the default launcher from LG,  the lines appear in the launcher too.

Comment: Also check in developer options , if they're is something related (tap on build number 7 times to reveal developer options). Another thing is long press on any icon to reveal menu and see if changing icon pack from there or other options help